# Azure Worker role and blob storage c# - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded files in blob storage. I am trying to download those files from worker role to do some processing on it. The container name is sent from the WebApi2 to the queue.

The worker role first fetches the container name from the queue and then tries to download the blobs within that container.

Below is the code for the name:

```
  public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Starting processing of messages");

        // Initiates the message pump and callback is invoked for each message that is received, calling close on the client will stop the pump.
        Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Process the message
                Trace.WriteLine("Processing Service Bus message: " + receivedMessage.SequenceNumber.ToString());
                string msg = "Container Name: " + receivedMessage.GetBody<String>();
                Trace.WriteLine("Processing Service Bus message: " + msg);

                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =   CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyStorage"));


                CloudBlobContainer imagesContainer = null;


                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(msg);


                // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
                imagesContainer.CreateIfNotExists();


                imagesContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });

                var blobs = imagesContainer.ListBlobs();
                var listOfFileNames = new List<string>();


                foreach (var blob in blobs)
                {
                    var blobFileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();
                    listOfFileNames.Add(blobFileName);
                    Trace.WriteLine(listOfFileNames);
                }

                if (listOfFileNames == null)
                {

                    Trace.WriteLine("present");
                }



                for (i = 1; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob signBlob =    imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(i + ".txt");

                    MemoryStream lms = new MemoryStream();
                    signBlob.DownloadToStream(lms);
                    lms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(lms);
                    Trace.WriteLine(SR);
                }


            }




            catch(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException e)
            {
                // Handle any message processing specific exceptions here
                Trace.WriteLine("Error:" + e);
            }
        });

        CompletedEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

I am getting the below Exception:

```
enter code hereException thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
```

Error:Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 677
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 199
   at WorkerRoleWithSBQueue1.WorkerRole.b__4_0(BrokeredMessage receivedMessage)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of the container you're trying to create? 400 error at the time of container creation usually indicates an invalid name for the container.

Comment: Can you access any blob from container through public http url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you're doing the following:

```
string msg = "Container Name: " + receivedMessage.GetBody<String>();
```

And then you're doing the following:

```
        imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(msg);
        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        imagesContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
```

So basically you're creating a container name of which starts with `Container Name` which is an invalid value for the container name. This is why you're getting the error.

Please see this link for valid naming convention for blob container: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx.

Comment: Yeaa SIr. The code was taking container name as "Container Name:" + msg" which was incorrect. The container name was only the value in the string 'msg'.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure if you have seen my comment about account key (I flagged your comment containing account key and it got deleted). If you have not done already, please change your account key ASAP.